# Plot two dataframes in different charts with shared selector/filter in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I have two pandas dataframes `data` and `data_queue` with the same structure containing similar data.
The former shall be plotted as a line while the latter as a scatter plot. 
I need a shared selector to filter on both charts. 
In the example below, the selector works only if I remove `scatter`.

How to achieve that in Altair?

Note: I need the last `layer` to add tooltip, rules, text, etc. to the line plot. For sake of readability, I omitted that part here.

```
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=data.koplus_name.unique().tolist())
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['koplus_name'], bind=input_dropdown, name='Koplus', init={'koplus_name': input_dropdown.options[0]})


line = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('yearmonthdatehoursminutes(timestamp)', title='timestamp', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(str(data.timestamp.min()), str(data.timestamp.min() + pd.Timedelta(value=1, unit='D'))))),
    y=alt.Y('value', axis=alt.Axis(title=''), scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, data.value.max()))),
    color=alt.Color('variable', legend=alt.Legend(title=None)),
)

scatter = alt.Chart(data_queue).mark_point().encode(
    x='green time',
    y='value',
)

chart = line + scatter

layer = alt.layer(
    chart
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
).properties(
    width=800, height=250
).interactive(bind_y=False)
```

[image: messy plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want data to respond to the same selection, it has to be part of the same data source. You can either join the datasets in pandas before creating the chart, or join the datasets with a [Lookup Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/lookup.html) within the Altair grammar.

Here is an example of the second approach, with some small datasets:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.arange(100),
    'y': np.random.randn(100).cumsum()
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.arange(100),
    'z': np.random.randn(100).cumsum()
})

selection = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

base = alt.Chart(df1).transform_lookup(
  lookup='x',
  from_=alt.LookupData(data=df2, key='x', fields=['z'])
).mark_point(color='steelblue').encode(
  x='x:Q',
  color=alt.condition(selection, alt.value('steelblue'), alt.value('lightgray'))
)

alt.layer(
  base.encode(y='y:Q'),
  base.encode(y='z:Q')
).add_selection(
  selection
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jake this effectively solves the question. I was hoping for something similar to matplotlib where I can print two DFs in two steps just by sharing the axis object. I had two time-series for which the merging was creating NaNs without a clear reason, thus plotting by sharing `ax` would be a quick(er) way to visualize that data.